# Deezer Track Embed Widget Seems to Require Flash (Broken on Safari 10 + FireFox)

Tags: html, flash, deezer

I am trying to embed the Deezer Track Embed Widget on a page. Both the iFrame and HTML5 versions seem to require Flash to play. So they are now not functioning in Safari 10 + FireFox.

http://developers.deezer.com/musicplugins/player?type=tracks&id=532744

Are there versions / settings which don't use Flash?

The error in both browsers is:

"Flash is not installed or is too old"

Comment: While you wait... did you try updating Flash Player plugin to the most recent? Also try to enable some Flash auto-update so you never get the error pop-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Flash is needed for the widget.

A full HTML5, flash-free player is in the works, but I cannot give you a release date.

Sorry for this inconvenience!

Comment: Any news on the HTML5 player? I'm still forced to use Flash, sadly. (Firefox 57 on Linux)

Comment: @TimVisée afaik it now works as HTML5 but only on browsers Chrome 55+ and Safari 10+

Comment: @Dusko Unfortunately the JavaScript SDK still requires Flash: "The Deezer web player requires Flash (for stream encryption purposes), the minimum required version is Flash Player 10.1. On mobile, the player will automatically fall back to 30-second previews." https://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/loadtracks